# Filtering in Vue, nested array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

Im trying to create a computed function that can filter out my Object by "alarms",

So I've created a computed function, called filteredAlarms, and in my loop im doing a v-for loop:

```
<li class="event-log__item timeline__item" v-for="(item, key) in filteredAlarms" :key="key">
```

And in my filter im trying to do the following:

```
let filteredAlarms = Object.keys(this.eventLog).forEach(key => {
  this.eventLog[key].filter(item => {
    return item.type.indexOf("alarm") > -1
  });
});

return filteredAlarms
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work - Im getting a an error: TypeError: this.eventLog.filter is not a function

What am I doing wrong? :)

The object im trying to filter is something similar to the one below:

```
"system_events": {
    "1013": [{
        "id": 25899,
        "timestamp": "2017-08-15T21:26:42Z",
        "type": "alarm",
        "code": 190,
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "appeared": "2017-08-15T21:26:40Z",
        "disappeared": null,
        "acknowlegded": null,
        "solved": null,
        "system_name": "Randers pr 44b sidste station"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 26157,
        "timestamp": "2017-08-15T21:32:17Z",
        "type": "warning",
        "code": 190,
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "appeared": "2017-08-15T21:32:06Z",
        "disappeared": null,
        "acknowlegded": null,
        "solved": null,
        "system_name": "Randers pr 44b sidste station"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 26387,
        "timestamp": "2017-08-15T21:37:38Z",
        "type": "info",
        "code": 190,
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "appeared": "2017-08-15T21:37:33Z",
        "disappeared": null,
        "acknowlegded": null,
        "solved": null,
        "system_name": "Randers pr 44b sidste station"
    }],
    "1015": [{
        "id": 23777,
        "timestamp": "2017-08-15T20:38:08Z",
        "type": "alarm",
        "code": 191,
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "appeared": "2017-08-15T20:38:00Z",
        "disappeared": null,
        "acknowlegded": null,
        "solved": null,
        "system_name": "Favrskov Svenstrup gyvelvej"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 23779,
        "timestamp": "2017-08-15T20:38:08Z",
        "type": "alarm",
        "code": 190,
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "appeared": "2017-08-15T20:37:58Z",
        "disappeared": null,
        "acknowlegded": null,
        "solved": null,
        "system_name": "Favrskov Svenstrup gyvelvej"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 23841,
        "timestamp": "2017-08-15T20:39:41Z",
        "type": "alarm",
        "code": 192,
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "appeared": "2017-08-15T20:39:31Z",
        "disappeared": null,
        "acknowlegded": null,
        "solved": null,
        "system_name": "Favrskov Svenstrup gyvelvej"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 25243,
        "timestamp": "2017-08-15T21:12:03Z",
        "type": "alarm",
        "code": 191,
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "appeared": "2017-08-15T21:11:55Z",
        "disappeared": null,
        "acknowlegded": null,
        "solved": null,
        "system_name": "Favrskov Svenstrup gyvelvej"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 25529,
        "timestamp": "2017-08-15T21:18:11Z",
        "type": "alarm",
        "code": 190,
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "appeared": "2017-08-15T21:18:00Z",
        "disappeared": null,
        "acknowlegded": null,
        "solved": null,
        "system_name": "Favrskov Svenstrup gyvelvej"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With forEach you don't filter anything, you iterate. And filter inside returns new array, so it also doesn't change `eventLog[key]`.

Try something like this instead:

```
let filteredAlarams = {}

Object.keys(this.eventLog).forEach(key => {
  filteredAlarams[key] = this.eventLog[key].filter(item => {
    return item.type.indexOf("alarm") > -1
  });
});

return filteredAlarms
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the value of `filteredAlarms` is `undefined`, since `forEach` does not return anything.

Secondly, you should know that `filter()` returns a new array. You are not using the new filtered array anywhere.

It could look like this

```
const filteredAlarms = Object.keys(this.eventLog).reduce((result, key) => {
     result[key] = this.eventLog[key].filter(item => {
       return item.type.indexOf("alarm") > -1
     })

     return result
}, {})

return filteredAlarms
```

And then there's the

```
TypeError: this.eventLog.filter is not a function
```

My wild guess is you're trying to iterate over the whole object posted above, but you should iterate over the `data.system_events` property.

Comment: `map` will produce an array, while I guess `filteredAlarms` needs to stay object.

Comment: @dfsq yes, I realized it now, I have edited the code.